# How can lock editing to one patricular line in graph editor?

Tags: graph-editor

I have many lines in graph editor but I sometime cannot select a right keyframe to edit because it selects a keyframe from nearby line. How can I select exact line I want to edit and lock editing to it so it wont select anything around it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click on the eye near the line name to hide it.

Comment: I know it, I can hide all other curves, but i just wonder if there is a hotkey to automatically hide all curves except the selected one

Comment: Shift H to hide every curve except selected, Alt H to unhide.

Comment: Thanks! That is almost exactly what I've been looking for